# (PHP+HTML) Codes inside PHP

Tags: php, html

I have some coding which has both PHP & HTML tags... it is a very big coding... now i want to add these coding inside PHP tag... i tried using "echo" statement and adding quotes, concatenation... it doesnt work and showing some error

here is a sample line..

```
<td>Developer</td><td>:</td><td><?php echo wpws_get_content($url,'.doc-header-link','','user_agent=FairAndroid.com&on_error=error_hide&cache=43289&callback=call')?></td>
```

the above line has lots of quotes, html and php... i have lots of lines like this...

what is the best way to include (HTML & PHP) inside PHP ??

Comment: There's really not a lot of good use cases for putting PHP in PHP. You mention "a lot of lines like this..." but the sample doesn't have any problems AFAIK. Can you post the error message as well?

Comment: i am getting error like unexpected use of "." ...

Comment: PHP usually tells you in which line the error happened. Edit your post and add the complete PHP error to it aswell as the affected lines of your file.

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing wrong with your line. Follow error you're seeing and try to correct them

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/3a329.php

Answer (score 0):

"adding quotes, concatenation" That's what you need, but it's kind of error-prone to reformat long lines:

```
echo '<td>Developer</td><td>:</td><td>'
    . wpws_get_content($url,'.doc-header-link','','user_agent=FairAndroid.com&on_error=error_hide&cache=43289&callback=call')
    . '</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion so that no matter how long your html codes just a simple include will simply insert it to your php file.

1. Put you html codes in a different file
2. Then just include it in your php file.

file.html

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

file.php

```
<?php

include("file.html");

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you want to print that chunk of code, you failed to escape the quotes and the special characters ( <, >, & and so on).

Splitted on multiple lines for better clarity.

```
<?php
    echo('<td>Developer</td>');
    echo('<td>:</td>');
    echo('<td>&lt;?php echo wpws_get_content($url, \'.doc-header-link\', \'\', \'user_agent=FairAndroid.com&amp;on_error=error_hide&amp;cache=43289&amp;callback=call\')?&gt;</td>');
?>
```

Comment: <?php inside the <?php will create problems ?

Comment: @Asho: There is no `<?php`, the `<` is escaped into its entity `&lt;` so your page will display you PHP code instead of executing it (that is, if it's what you want). P.s. for the downvoters: could you at least explain *why* you downvoted? Otherwise it's not really helpful.